# Vertically align a radial gradient

Tags: css

I've setup the following jsfiddle = https://jsfiddle.net/gfxjwuao/

```css
.skeleton-yqjgac1o2g6:empty {
  height: 133px; 
  background-color: red; 
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
  background-image: radial-gradient( circle 20px at 20px 20px, #F5F7F9 19px, transparent 20px );
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size: 40px 133px;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="skeleton-yqjgac1o2g6"></div>
```

All I want to do is vertically align the circle. I can horizontally center it all fine, but it just seems to ignore it vertically. Any ideas?

Using `background-position: center center` is ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried it like this, changing the coordinates of radial-gradient to "center":

```css
.skeleton-yqjgac1o2g6:empty {
  height: 133px; 
  background-color: red; 
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
  background-image: radial-gradient( circle 20px at center, #F5F7F9 19px, transparent 20px );
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size: 40px 133px;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<div class="skeleton-yqjgac1o2g6"></div>
```

Just a noob, though.
Can't really explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Just change background-image radial graidient y to 50%. or just copy paste answer below and look for reasoning by yourself. :)

```
.skeleton-yqjgac1o2g6:empty {height: 133px; background-color: red; border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px; background-image: radial-gradient( circle 20px at 20px 50%, #F5F7F9 19px, transparent 20px );background-repeat: repeat-y;background-size: 40px 133px;background-position: 50% 50%;vertical-align: center;}
```